# How To Convert C# String Quote to Javascript String Quote

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

In C#, I'm trying to convert a `DataTable` into a Javascript object through Razor syntax. However, when assigning string values to a Javascript key, the quote strings `"` get converted into HTML codes in Javascript `\&quot;`. How do I preserve the quote `"` in Javascript?

Example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @{
        string json = "";

        foreach (DataRow x in Model.MyDataTable.Rows)
        {
            json += "{field1: \"" + x["field1"].ToString() + "\"},";
        }

        json = json.TrimEnd(',');
    }

    var table = [@json];
</script>
```

What I'm expecting to see in Javascript debugger:

`[{field1: "0001"}, {field1: "0002"}]`

What I'm getting:

`[{field1: \&quot;0001\&quot;}, {field1: \&quot;0002\&quot;}]`

I've tried to use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode()` but this was returning a similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `RawString` instead of default `HtmlEncodedString`

```
   var table = [@Raw(json)];
```

Comment: Great, this works! Just FYI, as I'm using ASP.NET MVC, I needed to use `Html.Raw()` instead.

Comment: Have to wait 2 more mins before I can haha!